# Do you have to be the last editor for it to count against the editing badges?

Tags: support, badges, edit-badges

[SEDE Query 1](http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/q/5117/how-many-edits-until-strunk-white)
[SEDE Query 2](http://odata.stackexchange.com/meta/qt/5157/how-many-edits-have-I-made)

These two queries seem to imply that for an edit to count against the [Strunk and White badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) or the [Copy Editor badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/65/copy-editor), one needs to be the *most recent* editor.

However, the badge descriptions, which are `Edited 100/600 entries`, imply that one only has to be *an* editor, but not necessarily the most recent.

Are the two queries correct, or do edited edits count?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah your queries are not going to be accurate, the data dump does not contain Post History.

We look at the Post History table for these badges.