# Deleted users cause inaccurate "edited" info on posts

Tags: bug, edits, deleted-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit timestamp screws up when the last editor is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18754/edit-timestamp-screws-up-when-the-last-editor-is-deleted)

A user edited one of [my posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/57735/revisions), then subsequently had his account deleted. However, on the [actual question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57735/do-you-have-to-be-the-last-editor-for-it-to-count-against-the-editing-badges), the last edited user shows as me, even though it was the deleted user. My [profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/89334/waiwai933#qpage_1-apage_1-qsort_votes-asort_votes) shows the last edited user as [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community).

Screenshot of another example (see [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/42689/revisions)):

[image: screenshot demonstrating this behavior]

I'm not sure what the correct behaviour is—the original username is probably possible, as migrated posts without associated owners get a grayed out username, but Community might be the other option. Either way, I shouldn't be shown as the last edited user.

<sub>And since it's 24 Dec 2010 UTC, merry Christmas Eve to you all, and best wishes for unicorns in your stockings on the 25<sup>th</sup>.</sub>