# Why does asked and edited shows the same person?

Tags: support, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit timestamp screws up when the last editor is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18754/edit-timestamp-screws-up-when-the-last-editor-is-deleted)

URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458892/how-do-you-know-it-is-time-to-start-looking-for-another-job

I see the question added and edited by the same person.

My guess is that this happened because the last editor is not a part of the community anymore and the chronological successor to claim the edit is the author itself?

Is this an SO bug? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No idea but thanks for surfacing the post so it could be dispatched.

Comment: Do you mean similar to this? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73179/deleted-users-cause-inaccurate-edited-info-on-posts

Comment: @JasonPlank: Exactly :) With such prolific programmers on SO, why this was not rectified? curious...

Comment: Definitely seen this before and was immensely curious at the cause.

Comment: @naveen the question it is marked as a duplicate of is tagged [status-completed], but I wonder if that is erroneous.

Comment: @The I love the new look of your CV. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/kev :)

Comment: @Jason: that for sure is erroneous... relieved to know that SO team is almost human :P. this bug has been reported 2.5 years back :)

Comment: @Moderators:I see our [aforementioned post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458892/how-do-you-know-it-is-time-to-start-looking-for-another-job) as deleted. May I ask why?

Comment: @random: if this is a duplicate, the post you linked wont be having a status completed tag.

Comment: @TheP.G.RepMiningCo. - oops! ah what the hell it's christmas :)

Comment: @random Is it really a duplicate? That question is tagged `status-complete`, so presumably it's been fixed. Right?

Comment: Fixed if by design, yes, so completed @nul

Answer (score 3):

It indeed seems to be a bug.

The user who *really* edited the post last, Roger Pate, has since been deleted. That is probably the root cause.

Comment: What happened to Roger Pate?

Comment: Maybe he spread himself too thin?